# PYTHON TELEGRAM BOT - KeyError: 'message'

Tags: python, bots, telegram, sendmessage

I've created a bot in telegram last week and he works fine in private chat, but in group he doesn't receive `text` in message json received. I already set privacy off/no bot inline/set join groups on and still doesn't works.

example json received after type a pattern search in DM.

```
message--> {'update_id': 144970421, 'message': {'message_id': 114, 'from': {'id': 211279113, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Rafael', 'last_name': 'Ribeiro', 'username': 'aybararocks', 'language_code': 'en'}, 'chat': {'id': 211279113, 'first_name': 'Rafael', 'last_name': 'Ribeiro', 'username': 'aybararocks', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1671754018, 'text': 'rand'}}
```

example json received after type a pattern search in simple GROUP.

```
message--> {'update_id': 144970079, 'my_chat_member': {'chat': {'id': -1001857987984, 'title': 'Trying to suceed', 'type': 'supergroup'}, 'from': {'id': 211279113, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Rafael', 'last_name': 'Ribeiro', 'username': 'aybararocks', 'language_code': 'pt-br'}, 'date': 1671730720, 'old_chat_member': {'user': {'id': 5902418100, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'Wheel of Time Quotes || Rafa', 'username': 'wot_group_bot'}, 'status': 'left'}, 'new_chat_member': {'user': {'id': 5902418100, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'Wheel of Time Quotes || Rafa', 'username': 'wot_group_bot'}, 'status': 'member'}}}
```

only in first example I got text message.

My code is:

```
def parse_message(message):
    chat_id = message['message']['chat']['id']
    txt = message['message']['text']
    return chat_id, txt

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg = request.get_json()

        chat_id, txt = parse_message(msg)
        if 'rand' in txt.lower():
            tel_send_message(chat_id, f'<i>{quotes[randint(0, len(quotes)-1)]}</i>')

        return Response('ok', status=200)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The group update you got was not a chat message, but a group membership event.

The minimal way to avoid the KeyError exception is to ignore that update type with a try/except:

```
def parse_message(message):
    chat_id = message['message']['chat']['id']
    try:
        txt = message['message']['text']
    except KeyError:
        print("received unhandled message type")
        txt=''
    return chat_id, txt
```

If you want the bot to see group chat messages, you must promote it to a group admin in the group settings.